# Jooq 3.9 doesn't link MySQL columns to enums

Tags: java, mysql, enums, jooq

I am updating jooq from version **3.4.1** to **3.9.3** and noticed that models for tables that have `enum` fields in **MySQL 5.6** database are generated with `String` type instead.

The enum corresponding to the field is **properly** generated, it's just not linked to the pojo corresponding to the table.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar ENUM('BarBar') NOT NULL
}
```

This is an example of generated Pojo for the table **Foo**:

```
@Generated(
    value = {
        "http://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.9.0"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
public class Foo {
    private String bar;
}
```

and the enum which is **not** linked to the table pojo, although in its name contains **Foo** prefix of the table:

```
@Generated(
    value = {
        "http://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.9.0"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
public enum FooBar implements EnumType {

    BarBar("BarBar");

    private final String literal;

    // ...
}
```

I haven't changed any configuration, just jooq version. I would like to know if this is a bug or most likely some piece of configuration missing on my side.

This change was introduced between versions **3.8.8** and **3.9.0** but i haven't been able to narrow it down from release notes.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5725) that sort of corresponds to this but it shouldn't have went live, so it's possibly outdated configuration on my part.

Comment: It's probably a bug, and I have a slight feeling that this could be related to the interesting case-sensitivity (or not sensitivity, depending on the context) of MySQL schema names, i.e. this one: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86022. What's the schema name (case-sensitive) of your `foo` table?

Comment: @Lukas Eder Thank you again for help. Schema name is all lowercase, lets call it sguard. The table uses snake_case naming, exactly like this: foo_bar. The enum field in table is defined with CamelCase, sort of, since a first letter is also capital letter.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. The known issue is only related to schema names. I'll have to continue investigating this, might take a while though, as I cannot reproduce it yet...

Comment: Additional information, MySQL version is 5.6.32. Originally enum field had only one value, i have tried with two now but the same issue happens.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. This does look like a bug. I've registered an issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6349. Will confirm as soon as possible. A workaround might be to use a custom converter here to explicitly map the column to its enum type.

Comment: Are you using `<outputSchemaToDefault/>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why this could happen:

#### A bug in jOOQ related to `<outputSchemaToDefault/>`

This looks like bugs

- [#6367](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6367) - PostgreSQL enums aren't linked correctly from generated tables when `<outputSchemaToDefault/>` is true
- [#6395](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6395) - Definition.getQualifiedName() is wrong when `<outputSchemaToDefault/>` is set to true

Which will be fixed in jOOQ 3.10.0, 3.9.4, 3.8.8. The issue is related to setting the `<outputSchemaToDefault/>` flag to true.

#### You're excluding the enum type with your configuration

The `<includes/>` and `<excludes/>` configuration must ensure that the enum type is included as code generation output. The enum type is a synthetic type that behaves like a PostgreSQL enum type. It has a synthetic name that is made from: `[TABLE_NAME]_[COLUMN_NAME]`.

Note: In your case, I'm assuming this is done correctly, because you're getting the enum type itself. I'm adding this here for completeness' sake, in case someone else has similar issues.

Comment: Yup, it was the <outputSchemaToDefault/>